# A custom LEGO velociraptor

Tags: lego-group, customization

I would like to make a custom paint job on a LEGO velociraptor (to look more like the one in the LEGO Jurassic World game), but I don't want to paint it myself because I can't paint for the life of me so it would look bad and it probably wouldn't move. So I looked for a website to see if I could have one printed but I can't seem to find anything. Could someone help?

Answer (score 5):

In my understanding of the question, you want to take an existing [LEGO velociraptor](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=Raptor06) and repaint it, but you are afraid that doing a custom paint job will rub off quickly.

There is no easy solution for this, but here are a few tips:

1. You could send an email to the guys at [minifigs.me](http://www.minifigs.me) and see if they would be willing to help you with this, either as a one-off job (but it will cost you) or as an offering they wish to add to their collection. Their contact form is [here].(http://minifigs.me/make-me-a-minifig/contact/)
2. You could try and do this yourself. Removing the existing print from
   a raptor fig should be relatively easy ([this article at
   Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=4878&pid=78048&st=0&#entry78048)
   recommends Brasso and a paper towel/rag/cotton ball) even though
   that is very mildly abrasive and hence might leave some minor
   scratches. [Brickjournal](http://www.brickjournal.com/) ran a series
   of articles back in 2008 about minifig customization - I found [this
   online
   copy](http://www.fineclonier.com/101_2v2_Altering_the_color_of_LEGO_elements_-_Paints,_Dyes,_&_More.pdf) that explains how to give LEGO pieces a new paint color - they
   recommend acrylic paint. I also found [this link](http://www.customminifig.co.uk/custom-lego-painting-guide/) describing how to prime & paint LEGO minifigures. They recommend priming and sealing on top of an acrylic paint job.
3. To get the finer details, consider using a Sharpie pen.

Net - Customizing your velociraptor is definitely possible, but there is no "ready-to-go" customization service for this yet. Doing it yourself can be done, but it is not easy nor quick to do this, especially not if you're doing it the first time. Definitely not a job for kids.

Comment: You wer a great help sorry if the question didn't make sens I was half asleep wen I wrote it

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to build a velociraptor yourself, from basic bricks (as opposed to the single functional unit that LEGO introduced as part of the Jurassic World line). In this case I have no idea what search did you do, but just doing a Google search for "lego velociraptor" results in several models of varying proportions and looks:

- [1](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/57034)
- [2](http://rebrickable.com/mocs/jazlecraz/velociraptor-skeleton)
- [3](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pmiaki/3223863772)
- [4](https://www.flickr.com/photos/gambort/2670367671)
- [5](http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/129217)
- [6](http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/grohl666/8271Raptor/raptor09.jpg)

As for the painting and printing, could you please clarify your question? Why do you wish to paint or print and exactly what?